# How to flush frontend Cache from backend in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using YII2 Advanced, on the backend I needed an Action that invalidates the Cache in the frontend.

This is needed because I use [yii2mod/yii2-settings](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-settings), obiously, the settings are being cached on both ends. But I wasn't able to flush the cache from the backen with `Yii::$app->cache->flush();`, this will do it just in the backend.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So somehow I found that if I make a reference on the backend components, I end having access to flush on the backend.

On `\backend\config\main.php`

```
'components' => [
    //...
    'frontendCache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        'cachePath' => Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/runtime/cache'
    ],
]
```

Now in your controller

```
    Yii::$app->cache->flush(); //backend flush
    Yii::$app->frontendCache->flush(); //frontend flush
```

This took me a while to figure this out, so I hope this helps someone.